# Device driver software was not successfully installed

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I have a USB stick that was formatted with FAT32. It worked fine but all of a sudden I receive only the error *"Device driver software was not successfully installed"* whenever I plug it in a USB port.

I tried other sticks (FAT and NTFS) and all of them installed correctly.

What could be causing this?

Comment: It's probably not the file system but the drive itself. Try it on another computer.

Comment: Do all the devices have same response or only this drive?

Comment: Can you test the drive with another computer? Do you experience the same issue?

Comment: @avirk Only this drive.

Comment: @emb1995 Haven't tested it on other computers but I have I have switched my OS to x64 ffrom x86 and it's the same issue.

Comment: If we really want to start isolating this issue, we need to try a different computer. At the very least, try a different USB port. If neither worked, then you will need to dig a grave for your drive.

Comment: Try to uninstall the device driver from the Device Manager and then re-install the driver. If it does not do the trick then try to update device driver. Also see the manufacturer site for the latest driver.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

1. Open Device Manager and identify which object the USB drive maps to
2. Unplug the drive
3. Uninstall the Device mapped to this drive completely

   - 3a. You may need to completely uninstall the driver for it if it does not use generic Windows drivers
4. Try installing the driver software BEFORE reinserting the USB stick - note where the drive files are located once installed
5. Insert the USB stick

   - 5a. If Windows cannot automatically find the correct drivers (you installed) then manually update the driver and locate the driver you installed
6. If still no luck, you may need to repeat the above process but before re-installing also delete any registry entries that are specifically for this USB stick

   - 6a. You need to clearly identify the drive if you can by vendor or model. Drives and drivers are usually associated in the Registry using UUIDs. Also, when you move a USB device from one physical USB port to another sometimes (often!) Windows will create a whole new set of registry entries... for the same device in a different USB port! It is these 'duplicate' registry keys/entries that may need to be deleted to really get Windows back to a state of "I have no knowledge of this drive so let's install it fully".

## DISCLAIMER:

EDIT THE WINDOWS REGISTRY AT YOUR OWN RISK! DON'T DO IT IF YOU ARE NOT CONFIDENT THAT YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING!